# Custom install on wrong disk

Tags: system-installation, customization, preseed

I'm trying to install a custom Ubuntu iso on my computer, but it keeps installing it on the USB key where I have the ISO, even though I specified "/dev/sda".

Does anyone know what it's from?

Comment: you have to give more details on how you are installing. is it by bootable usb?
you have many tutorials arround the web on how to do it properly if you have doubts.i say this because there few different ways to do it

Comment: Yes I use a bootable usb key

Comment: /dev/sdX assignments are non-persistent -- they can be different each boot. So "I specified /dev/sda" doesn't really mean anything useful. Perhaps that time sda was indeed the USB key. You must double-check the /dev/sdx assignments before installing.

Comment: @user535733 That's exactly what happened, the /dev/sda was the usb key in this case.

Comment: What "custom Ubuntu iso" are you using?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've created an automated installation of Ubuntu 20.04.1 with my custom preseed

Comment: Hard to rule out the changes you made then.

Comment: Are you using `Something else` when installing?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I only change the preseed file and the file isolinux.cfg

Comment: @C.S.Cameron What do you mean by "Something else" ?

Comment: When Installing and you get to "Installation type" there is an option "Something else", it used to be called "Manual". It gives you the option of which partitions and disks to use and how to divide up the disks. You should probably be using it.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I've created my own partman recipe, it work perfectly on my test VM